# R find order of a vector

Tags: r, sorting

I have these two vectors:

```
x=c('a','c','b','b','c','a','d','d')
y=c(1, 4, 2, 4, 5, 9, 3, 3)
```

I want the order of `x` based on value of `y` such that each group in `x` are ordered following their minimum in `y`. Moreover within each group `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, I want the order depending on ascending values of `y`.

eg the result of this ordering per group is:

```
x |a a b b d d c c
y |1 9 2 4 3 3 4 5
```

Hence the output must be:

```
output = c(1, 7, 3, 4, 8, 2, 5, 6)
```

I tried to use `ave` but can't combine both:

```
> ave(y, x, FUN=function(u) rank(u, ties.method='first'))
[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 2
> ave(y, x, FUN=min)
[1] 1 4 2 2 4 1 3 3
```

Comment: A `data.table` solution for this problem would be interesting, too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to order first by the grouped `y` minimum and then by the `y` value itself, so you should pass these as the first and second arguments to the `order` function:

```
ordering <- order(ave(y, x, FUN=min), y)
x[ordering]
# [1] "a" "a" "b" "b" "d" "d" "c" "c"
y[ordering]
# [1] 1 9 2 4 3 3 4 5
```

Comment: I got completely confused with `order` and `rank`, thanks for the very neat answer! I did not know `order` can take several arguments, it's really insane!